# How to pick an item from list by strings trailing number

Tags: python, list, python-3.6

Im trying to make an app to find lastest anime episode in a folder.
Im now at the point where i have a list of items in following format:
`episode_name - ep_num` ie. `naruto - 11`,  `naruto - 12`, `bleach - 11`, `bleach - 12` etc. and i have it all saved to a list, but i cannot figure out a way to find the latest episode for all series.

So i need a way to create a new list that has just the: `anime_name - latest_ep_num` for each series so i can then check if a new episode is out on some website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like the following to get max out

```
max(anime_list, key = lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1]))
```

And an example to distinguish between different series, and get the max for each:

```
anime_list = ['naruto - 11', 'naruto - 12', 'naruto - 13','not naruto - 12','not naruto - 13']
import itertools
g = itertools.groupby(anime_list,lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
f = [(series, max(list(episode),key=lambda x: x.split('-')[1])) for series,episode in g]
```

And if you have episodes which have dashes in the name, as opposed to just preceding the episode number, you can use the following helper function to separate the episode name / number.

```
import re

episode = 'naruto - o no dash - 12'

def split_episodes(episode):
    ep = re.split('( - )',episode)
    return [''.join(ep[0:-2]), ep[-1]]

print(split_episodes(episode))
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. One problem though, here is a sample of the printout: `('Kyoukai', 'Kyoukai no Rinne - 51'), ('M3', 'M3 - Sono Kuroki Hagane - 03'), ('Made', 'Made in Abyss - 07')`. Now im guessing the lambda x: x.split()[0], is splitting the the string and taking first index and turning that into a "key" for the series that series.  I think i can remote that somehow, ill have to check when i get back to my coding pc.

Comment: I didn't have all your inputs so I made the assumption that the format is always `series - episode`, and split on the `-`.  There will be problems if the actual series name itself contains `-`.

Comment: Actually, the code works perfectly even with series that have "-" in the actual name for somereason. The only problem i had was that the index[0] was inserted into the list aswell, so it the list came out as `'naruto', 'naruto - 10'` but that was easy to fix with `for line in f: latest_list.append(line[1])` so i only appeded the [1] index and got a nice list with with just anime name and latest ep num.

Comment: nevermind, doesnt actually work with shows what have "-" in the actual name, it just prints the first episode it finds. Took a file to find the error, not that many shows that have - in the name  :)

Comment: im not good enough at coding yet to understand how to use the code for split episodes. BUT by playing around with the code you provided earlier, i just removed `[1]` from `f = [(series, max(list(episode),key=lambda x: x.split('-')[1])) for series,episode in g] ` and now the code seems to work, i wont even try to say i understand how or why, but it does by removing the `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have:

```
l = ['naruto - 11',  'naruto - 13', 'naruto - 12']
max(l, key = lambda x: int(x.split('- ')[1]))
```

Credits to @Solaxun. I initially did:

```
l = ['naruto - 11',  'naruto - 13', 'naruto - 12']
sorted([i.split('- ') for i in l])[-1]
```

What is not better than the first option.